# Squid StoreId rewrite

Tags: configuration, proxy, squid

I try to configure my proxy to de-duplicate some cached files.
Some site add query-string at the end of URL and so the file is cached multiple times. Ex :

- http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u75-b13/jre-7u75-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=kjzeghfhrehbfgjernf
- http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u75-b13/jre-7u75-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=jzehrguihegeijhpijf

I would like to create et rewrite rule for storeId like that :

```
^http:\/\/download\.oracle\.com\/otn\-pub\/java\/([a-zA-Z0-9\/\.\-\_]+\.(tar\.gz)) http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/$1
```

but I have'nt found documention about how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after long research I have find the answer to my question. I write here if case of someone else have the same question.

First of all, I have install Squid 3.4, the first version witch support StoreId rewrite.
Second, after reading StoreId documentation :

- wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/StoreID
- wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/StoreID/DB

and lot of google search I found this perl program http://pastebin.ca/2422099. It take a database file as first argument, you can find examples in the second link before. In the file I have had a line as above :

```
^http:\/\/download\.oracle\.com\/otn\-pub\/java\/([a-zA-Z0-9\/\.\-\_]+\.(tar\.gz))  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/$1
```

Third, in my squid.conf, I had this line :

```
store_id_program /usr/local/squid/store-id.pl /usr/local/squid/store_id_db
store_id_children 5 startup=1
```

**store_id_program** is the path to the perl file with in argument the database file.
**store_id_children** represent the number of subprocess allowed to the program, maximum 5, 1 at the beginning.

In the same squid.conf I replace this line :

```
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0       0%      0
```

by

```
refresh_pattern -i cgi-bin        0       0%      0
```

to allow caching url with query string.

Last, I ensure that the store-id.pl has 'x' permission

Hope this help :)

PS: Just a trick, in the db file, you must have to columns separate by a tabulation (not a space). To be sure, you can use this command (find in doc):

```
cat dbfile | sed -r -e 's/\s+/\t/g' |sed '/^\#/d' >cleaned_db_file
```